# Do the determination of conserved quantity in QM can use other operator instead of Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian, time-evolution

The conserved quantity in quantum mechanic determine by
$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle Q\rangle = \frac{-1}{i\bar{h}}\langle\psi|[H,Q]|\psi\rangle+\langle\psi|\frac{dQ}{dt}|\psi\rangle$$

First: From the equation, $Q$ will conserved if $[H,Q] = 0$. I understand that this will be true if $H \neq H(t)$. If $H = H(t)$ and **suppose $Q$ is conserved**, then the $[H,Q]$ will not equal to zero. The result will give that $Q$ is not conserved. This will mislead understanding in $Q$, no?

Second: Suppose $H \neq H(t)$, $H$ is conserved quantity then $[H,Q]$ is just a "is $Q$ commute with the conserved quantity $H$ or not". If there is a quantity that conserved, $A$, can i use $A$ instead of $H$?

Thrid: This equation is like this due to the time-dependent Schrodinger equation that $i\bar{h}\frac{d\psi}{dt} = H\psi$. Is there any explanation "Why connserved quantity have to do with $H$" other than $i\bar{h}\frac{d\psi}{dt} = H\psi$?

Comment: We are talking about conservation in time. The Hamiltonian operator generates time evolution. Which other operator do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

If $H=H(t)$, then Q is in fact still conserved if and only if it commutes with the Hamiltonian at all times--it's just much more difficult (often not possible) to find such quantities.

An example: If you have a time-dependent Hamiltonian such that $[H(t),H(t')]\ne0$, then even Energy is not conserved!

You can't replace just any conserved quantity A with H in the Equation--the Hamiltonian is the generator of translations in time, thus if Q doesn't commute with H, Q won't stay constant!

You can think of the Schrodinger Equation as the statement that "the Hamiltonian is the generator of time translations" thus, there isn't any other explanation. However, I think this explanation is a rather deep one.